# Theming ActionarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, theming

When theming my actionbar from the actionbarsherlock library i keep getting error:

Requires API 11 using min SDK 8

I dont get it Actionbar sherlock is for Android 2.X+ right? is there something i can do to fix this nuisance.

```
<resources >

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

// EDIT

ActionBarSherlock comes from Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 0):

```
Holo.Theme.Light
```

Your not using sherlock at all?

typical usage:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I am. Holo.Theme.Light is from HoloEverywhere which implements actionbarsherlock

Comment: My mistake, where in your original post did you state that?

Comment: Also, are you not meant to use Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock on HoloEverywhere? and parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"